# Setting custom font programmatically

Tags: java, android, textview, android-typeface

Fairly straightforward. It doesn't seem to be wanting to work for me. The error I get is that `getAssets()` is red and it says `Cannot resolve method 'getAssets()'`.

```
    text_View = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.textDesigner);
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf");
    text_View.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

The path for my font is: `C:\Users\Joe\AndroidStudioProjects\my-app\app\src\main\assets\fonts\Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf`

What's going on?

Comment: are you on activity or on fragment?

Comment: getActivity().getAssets()

Comment: Any reason for all the down votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to call the fragment's activity and then the assets

```
getActivity().getAssets()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Fragment replace

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf");
```

with

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf");
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The this object is not referring to your activity. Use

```
WhatevernameActivity.this.getAssets();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set typeface on textview
public static void SetTypeFace(Context ctx, TextView tv) {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),
            "Telex-Regular.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(font);
}
```

Pass Context and your textview in this mettod